# SQL Find out which login/user has modified a table structure

Tags: sql-server, ddl, last-modified

I need to find all DDL operations executed and the user associated about a table in a SQL Server database.

How can I do that?

PS:
The operation has been already executed.

Comment: Use DDL triggers. [DDL Triggers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/triggers/ddl-triggers?view=sql-server-2017)

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve it by [WMI Events](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/wmi-provider-server-events/understanding-the-wmi-provider-for-server-events?view=sql-server-2017) - SQL Alert

Following script would create alert in SQL Agent section:

**Step1 - WMI Event Alert**

These part of the code to be replaced as per your environment:
`\\.\root\Microsoft\SqlServer\ServerEvents\SQLInstanceName` at the end enter the SQL Instance name. if your server is default instance use `MSSQLSERVER`

```
USE [msdb]
GO

EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_add_alert @name=N'WMI - DDL_TABLE_EVENTS', 
        @message_id=0, 
        @severity=0, 
        @enabled=1, 
        @delay_between_responses=0, 
        @include_event_description_in=1, 
        @category_name=N'[Uncategorized]', 
        @wmi_namespace=N'\\.\root\Microsoft\SqlServer\ServerEvents\SQLInstanceName', 
        @wmi_query=N'select * from DDL_TABLE_EVENTS WHERE (DatabaseName ISA "MyDB")', --- This alert on one database, you can remove "WHERE" caluse to focus on all tables
        @job_id=N'819e9aea-95dd-49d3-b518-49060b1910a4'
GO
```

**Step 2 - SQL Job**

Script to create **SQL Job** that triggered by Alert (Created step 1). it would also load the same event information into local audit table that desire to have.

These part of the code to be replaced as per your environment:
`DatabaseName.DBO.YourAuditLogTable`
`@profile_name = ''ProfileName''`
`@recipients = ''youremail@domain.AE''`

```
USE [msdb]
GO

BEGIN TRANSACTION
DECLARE @ReturnCode INT
SELECT @ReturnCode = 0

IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT name FROM msdb.dbo.syscategories WHERE name=N'[Uncategorized (Local)]' AND category_class=1)
BEGIN
EXEC @ReturnCode = msdb.dbo.sp_add_category @class=N'JOB', @type=N'LOCAL', @name=N'[Uncategorized (Local)]'
IF (@@ERROR <> 0 OR @ReturnCode <> 0) GOTO QuitWithRollback

END

DECLARE @jobId BINARY(16)
EXEC @ReturnCode =  msdb.dbo.sp_add_job @job_name=N'WMI Response - DDL_TABLE_EVENTS', 
        @enabled=1, 
        @notify_level_eventlog=0, 
        @notify_level_email=0, 
        @notify_level_netsend=0, 
        @notify_level_page=0, 
        @delete_level=0, 
        @description=N'Sends email to DBA on DDL_TABLE Event', 
        @category_name=N'[Uncategorized (Local)]', 
        @owner_login_name=N'DBA', @job_id = @jobId OUTPUT
IF (@@ERROR <> 0 OR @ReturnCode <> 0) GOTO QuitWithRollback
/****** Object:  Step [Send e-mail in response to WMI alert(s)]    Script Date: 8/19/2019 12:52:29 PM ******/
EXEC @ReturnCode = msdb.dbo.sp_add_jobstep @job_id=@jobId, @step_name=N'Send e-mail in response to WMI alert(s)', 
        @step_id=1, 
        @cmdexec_success_code=0, 
        @on_success_action=1, 
        @on_success_step_id=0, 
        @on_fail_action=2, 
        @on_fail_step_id=0, 
        @retry_attempts=0, 
        @retry_interval=0, 
        @os_run_priority=0, @subsystem=N'TSQL', 
        @command=N'DECLARE @p_subject NVARCHAR(255), @Body nvarchar (2000);
DECLARE @TargetServer nvarchar (25),
        @TargetInstance nvarchar (25),
        @TargetDatabase nvarchar (25),
        @SourceHost nvarchar (25),
        @EventType nvarchar (25),
        @SourceLogin nvarchar (25); 

Select @TargetServer = ''$(ESCAPE_SQUOTE(WMI(ComputerName)))''
select @TargetInstance = ''$(ESCAPE_SQUOTE(WMI(SQLInstance)))''
select @TargetDatabase = ''$(ESCAPE_SQUOTE(WMI(DatabaseName)))''
select @SourceLogin = ''$(ESCAPE_SQUOTE(WMI(LoginName)))'';
select @EventType = ''$(ESCAPE_SQUOTE(WMI(__CLASS)))'';

SELECT  @p_subject = N''WMI Alert: '' + @EventType +
        '' [$(ESCAPE_SQUOTE(WMI(DatabaseName)))]:[$(ESCAPE_SQUOTE(WMI(ComputerName)))\$(ESCAPE_SQUOTE(WMI(SQLInstance)))].'' ;
select @Body = N''WMI Alert DDL TABLE EVENTS: Computer Name: $(ESCAPE_SQUOTE(WMI(ComputerName)));
SQL Instance: $(ESCAPE_SQUOTE(WMI(SQLInstance))); 
Database: $(ESCAPE_SQUOTE(WMI(DatabaseName)));
Login Name: $(ESCAPE_SQUOTE(WMI(LoginName)));
PostTime: $(ESCAPE_SQUOTE(WMI(PostTime)));
EventType: $(ESCAPE_SQUOTE(WMI(__CLASS)));
Command: $(ESCAPE_SQUOTE(WMI(TSQLCommand)));
'';

insert into DatabaseName.DBO.YourAuditLogTable
([EventCreatedOn] ,[EventType] ,[TargetServerName] ,[TargetInstanceName],[TargetDatabaseName], [SourceLogin] ,[AuditData])
values
(GETDATE(), @EventType, @TargetServer, @TargetInstance, @TargetDatabase, @SourceLogin, @Body);

EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail
    @profile_name = ''ProfileName'', -- update with your values
    @recipients = ''youremail@domain.AE'', -- update with your values
    @subject = @p_subject,
    @body = @Body
', 
        @database_name=N'msdb', 
        @flags=0
IF (@@ERROR <> 0 OR @ReturnCode <> 0) GOTO QuitWithRollback
EXEC @ReturnCode = msdb.dbo.sp_update_job @job_id = @jobId, @start_step_id = 1
IF (@@ERROR <> 0 OR @ReturnCode <> 0) GOTO QuitWithRollback
EXEC @ReturnCode = msdb.dbo.sp_add_jobserver @job_id = @jobId, @server_name = N'(local)'
IF (@@ERROR <> 0 OR @ReturnCode <> 0) GOTO QuitWithRollback
COMMIT TRANSACTION
GOTO EndSave
QuitWithRollback:
    IF (@@TRANCOUNT > 0) ROLLBACK TRANSACTION
EndSave:
GO
```

Comment: And what if the operation has been already executed? this solution is for the future operations.

Comment: I don't think (by default in SQL Server) you can retrieve such information.

Comment: No, it's not something you can achieve on data previous to the triggers structure creation...

Answer (score 0):

i've found this one but it retrieves only the last operations

```
begin try
    declare @enable int
    select top 1 @enable = convert(int,value_in_use) from sys.configurations where name = 'default trace enabled'
    if @enable = 1 --default trace is enabled
    begin 
            declare @d1 datetime;
            declare @diff int;
            declare @curr_tracefilename varchar(500); 
            declare @base_tracefilename varchar(500); 
            declare @indx int ;
            declare @temp_trace table (
                    obj_name nvarchar(256) collate database_default
            ,       database_name nvarchar(256) collate database_default
            ,       start_time datetime
            ,       event_class int
            ,       event_subclass int
            ,       object_type int
            ,       server_name nvarchar(256) collate database_default
            ,       login_name nvarchar(256) collate database_default
            ,       application_name nvarchar(256) collate database_default
            ,       ddl_operation nvarchar(40) collate database_default 
            );

            select @curr_tracefilename = path from sys.traces where is_default = 1 ; 
            set @curr_tracefilename = reverse(@curr_tracefilename)
            select @indx  = PATINDEX('%\%', @curr_tracefilename) 
            set @curr_tracefilename = reverse(@curr_tracefilename)
            set @base_tracefilename = LEFT( @curr_tracefilename,len(@curr_tracefilename) - @indx) + '\log.trc';

            insert into @temp_trace 
            select ObjectName
            ,       DatabaseName
            ,       StartTime
            ,       EventClass
            ,       EventSubClass
            ,       ObjectType
            ,       ServerName
            ,       LoginName
            ,       ApplicationName
            ,       'temp'
            from ::fn_trace_gettable( @base_tracefilename, default ) 
            where EventClass in (46,47,164) and EventSubclass = 0 and DatabaseID <> 2 

            update @temp_trace set ddl_operation = 'CREATE'where event_class = 46
            update @temp_trace set ddl_operation = 'DROP' where event_class = 47
            update @temp_trace set ddl_operation = 'ALTER' where event_class = 164

            select @d1 = min(start_time) from @temp_trace
            set @diff= datediff(hh,@d1,getdate())
            set @diff=@diff/24; 

            select  @diff as difference
            ,       @d1 as date
            ,       object_type as obj_type_desc 
            ,       * 
            from @temp_trace where object_type not in (21587)
            order by start_time desc
    end 
    else 
    begin 
            select top 0 1 as difference, 1 as date, 1 as obj_type_desc, 1 as obj_name, 1 as dadabase_name, 1 as start_time, 1 as event_class, 1 as event_subclass, 1 as object_type, 1 as server_name, 1 as login_name, 1 as application_name, 1 as ddl_operation 
    end
    end try
    begin catch
    select -100 as difference
    ,       ERROR_NUMBER() as date
    ,       ERROR_SEVERITY() as obj_type_desc
    ,       ERROR_STATE() as obj_name
    ,       ERROR_MESSAGE() as database_name
    ,       1 as start_time, 1 as event_class, 1 as event_subclass, 1 as object_type, 1 as server_name, 1 as login_name, 1 as application_name, 1 as ddl_operation 
    end catch
```